# hls segments are getting skipped in set-top box but getting downloaded properly on laptop

Tags: hls.js

We are trying to write an app which should play a recording which is on the server. These videos are in hls format. We are using hls.js player to play these videos. When we try to run the app on the laptop, browser is downloading all the hls segments are properly and able to play. But when we ran the same application on set-top box, after downloading some segments, it is directly downloading the last segment by skipping all other segments as attached in the screenshot.

[image]

From the screenshot, after segment 28, segment 208 is getting downloaded and no error is getting displayed on the console. We are using Opera browser both for laptop and set-top box. Can anyone please let me know how to fix the issue.